# Why my .cshtml files has no intellisense in VS 17 on Mac

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-mac

How can I fix my IDE so that VS 2017 on mac can have intellisense on `.cshtml` files? other files are okay but this one has just refused.

Comment: happens sometimes to me. I have a windows though. I close and reopen the files and it works. Have you tried reopening the project?

Comment: 2017 has an issue with intellisense randomly shutting down, particularly in large files.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane, reopening doesn't work for me , it's really bad for such issue

Comment: Because it's [not supported on vs-mac](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/19266271-razor-intellisense-should-include-in-vs-for-mac-st)

Comment: Rather than shifting to windows what's the other option @stuartd

Comment: I believe [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) supports intellisense for razor, but it's not free.

Comment: Man thats really bad

Comment: Can't resharper help here

Comment: Well, Resharper doesn't run in vs-mac so no.

Comment: Man this is really so bad

Comment: Have you tried **Visual Studio Code**?

Comment: @SushiHangover, am not getting what you are saying

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris https://code.visualstudio.com